# Batch file to create folder with name based on input information then copy into it another folder's contents

Tags: batch-file, windows-10-desktop

So what I am trying to do it make a batch file which copies contents of an existing folder into a newly created folder. I have been able to get by with a MKDIR a new folder and then XCOPY into the new folder and rename it manually.

Is it possible to have a batch file ask for information then rename the file itself and copy the needed information into the new folder?

Answer (score 0):

The question is very unclear and actually off topic, but if I get you correctly you want something similar to this?

```
@echo off
cls
set /p "newfolder=Type a name of the folder you want to create : "
cls
set /p "source=Type the source path of files to copy to %newfolder%: "
mkdir "%newfolder%"
xcopy "%source%\*" "%newfolder% /Y
pause
```

Comment: Sorta. Sorry I'm limited on what I can put on here because of NDA. I will try that tomorrow and get back to you. Thank you.